# Ошибка "Cannot find java.exe" при установке iReport

Tags: java, jasperreports

В задании нужно сначала при помощи **iReport** сделать макет отчёта для запроса к базе данных, затем сделать аналогичный макет для запроса через **jdbc**, с которым я тоже ещё только собираюсь начать знакомство.

Дело в том, что после установки скаченного *iReport-5.6.0-windows-installer.exe* с официального сайта пишет:

> *Cannot find java.exe*
>
> *Neither (null)\jre\bin\java.exe nor (null)\bin\java.exe exists.*

Изменение в *ireport.conf* с у казанием, где лежит JDK, а имено: *jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11"*, не помогает (с двойными слэшами тоже).

P.S. Если в итоге как-то удастся запустить это, то хотелось бы узнать, как потом подключить его к **java**-коду.

Comment: Очень похоже, что нужно задать переменную окружения `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 4):

Эсли я не ошибаюсь, JasperReports писался на java 6 или 7. У вас прописана 8, попробуйте поменять на 6 или 7.

Comment: Спасибо! в файле "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaspersoft\iReport-5.6.0\bin\ ireport.conf исправил строку где указал старую версию явы. все заработало. *Default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using `--jdkhome <dir>` switch*.  `jdkhome="D:\jre"`